# Problems creating required field validator dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, webforms, code-behind

I am storing settings in the database for which objects need to be validated along with there properties. To do this I am hoping to create them dynamically from a class which is called on page load.

I am able to create the validators from the class with what I believe are the correct minimum properties but afterwards they clearly don't work and when I do a submit I get no error message in the summary.

I have submitted my last attempt below which shows me trying to add them into a placeholder.

```
//In the class.

 public class ObjectSetup
    {
        static public DataTable GetPageValidators(int PageID)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GetConnector"].ConnectionString))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("PL_Objects_Validation_Get", conn);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageID", PageID);

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

            da.Fill(ds);

            dt = ds.Tables[0];
        }


        foreach (DataRow R in dt.Rows)
        {
            Guid ControlID = new Guid();

            RequiredFieldValidator RFV = new RequiredFieldValidator();
            RFV.ID = ControlID.ToString();
            RFV.ControlToValidate = R[0].ToString();
            RFV.ErrorMessage = R[1].ToString();
            RFV.Display = ValidatorDisplay.None;
            RFV.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            RFV.Enabled = true;
            RFV.Visible = true;

            PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(RFV);
        }



        return dt;
    }

//In the pages code-behind.


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable dtValidators = ObjectSetup.GetPageValidators(3);
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sam stated, you should create your controls in the Page_Init event. You also need to re-create dynamic controls every time on postbacks, so try the following:

```
protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtValidators = ObjectSetup.GetPageValidators(3);
}
```

Also are you actually adding your dynamic placeholder (PlaceHolder1) to the page anywhere?

One last point, if you use `new Guid()` your controls will all have the same ID, use `Guid.NewGuid()` instead, or you can not set the Control.ID property at all.

Comment: In your static GetPageValidators you are adding your dynamic RequiredFieldValidators to a dynamic Placeholder. How are you then adding this Placeholder to your Page? I suggest you return the Placeholder from the method and then add this to the Page controls.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in first place, as you will have more problems with when dynamically adding validators.

For a `CustomValidator` you need to set the following properties(or at least in my case I had these properties):

```
validator.ControlToValidate = control.ID;
validator.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
validator.EnableClientScript = true;
validator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.None;
```

Secondly in order for your validator to get added to page tree control tree you need to add them to Page_Init event otherwise there won't be in `ViewState`.

Comment: I have read that the every field apart from the required field validator will not fire if the textbox is empty so will I be able to use it for the required fields still? I also tried your Page Init with the code I already have and it still didn't work.

Comment: Yes you will be able to use it..try changing it to customvalidator.

Comment: The code you show above does not have any validation expression so how will it know what to check on postback?

Comment: Whether I use a required or custom validator they both do nothing, could you have a quick look at my code and see if you can see anything missing because at the moment they just arent being registered. In the code behind I believe you would use this.form.add(RFV) but in the class I'm not sure what to use.